# Write a DTD for XML data set (Beginner)

Tags: xml, dtd

I'm just learning about databases. I'm trying to write a DTD for the following XML data set:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/dbclass-resources/docs/countries.xml

At this point, I've tried a few options but am unsuccessful. Can someone please show me how to correctly write a DTD for the above data set (I've pasted a failed attempt of mine below).

```
<!ELEMENT countries (country*)>
<!ELEMENT country (language?, city?)
    <!ATTLIST country name CDATA #IMPLIED
                      population CDATA #IMPLIED
                      area CDATA #IMPLIED>
    <!ATTLIST language percentage CDATA #IMPLIED
<!ELEMENT city CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

Comment: Were are your `ELEMENT` definitions for `country` and `language`?  Every element in your XML has to be specified in an `ELEMENT` DTD entry.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, don't I have an ELEMENT definition for country already?

Comment: Would you be able to edit what I did? I have tried this a few times already unsuccessfully and feel like just seeing it correctly will help me relate it back to the data set itself.

Comment: Before you spend a lot of time on this, you may want to look into XML Schema, which replaced DTDs quite some time ago. I'm also not sure why you seem to be under the impression databases and XML are related.

Comment: It's really quite simple. You need an `!ELEMENT` for every distinct element type in your XML, which includes `countries`, `country`, `city`, `language`, `name` and `population`. So far you have the first three. The nesting hierarchy is specified by the list of sub-elements in each element definition NOT by nesting DTD elements.  Also, `!ATTLIST` does not nest inside anything.

Comment: A small note: the original XML document, posted in an external link, is not available any longer. For future reference, would you be so kind as to directly include the original XML again? I'm well aware that this question was answered almost a decade ago, but it _is_ still pertinent, and it would be nice to know what you're talking about :) [Granted, it should be possible to figure it out from the DTD posted by @daniel-haley on his answer...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues that I noticed with your attempt.

The first thing I noticed is that it doesn't look like you know how to use the occurrence indicators correctly. You have `country` defined as `(language?, city?)` which means zero or one `language` followed by zero or one `city`. This is not what appears in the data. Sometimes there are no city/language elements and sometimes there are more.

I also noticed that you are not closing a few of your declarations with `>` properly (an example is the declaration for `country`).

Also, this is invalid:

```
<!ELEMENT city CDATA #IMPLIED>
```

It looks like an element declaration and an attribute declaration had a baby. ;-)

Here's an example of a DTD that works that you can use for reference:

```
<!ELEMENT countries (country)+>

<!ELEMENT country (city*,language*)>
<!ATTLIST country
          area       CDATA #REQUIRED
          name       CDATA #REQUIRED
          population CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT city (name,population)>

<!ELEMENT language (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST language
          percentage CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>

<!ELEMENT population (#PCDATA)>
```

Here's a shortcut to a quickref that will help a lot with DTD syntax: http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/XMLquickref.pdf

Comment: Hi Daniel, would you be able to help w an additional inquiry I have about dtd's. It is for an online course I am taking. Would you be willing to exchange your email for direct message? Thanks for your help

Comment: The quickref is _very_ useful! So useful, in fact, that it would be a pity that Mulberry Tech took it down (which, fortunately, did _not_ happen in almost a decade). Would it be possible to add it as a SO resource of some sort?